# Объявление и типизация аргументов абстрактной функции

Tags: php, ооп

Почему нельзя написать вот так?

```
abstract class AbstractResultHandler
{
    abstract public function handle(string $name, AbstractRequest $request);
}
```

и указать в экземпляре класса в функции вторым аргументом конкретный тип класса, который унаследован от AbstractRequest?

```
сlass ResultHandlerA extends AbstractResultHandler
{
    public function handle(string $name, RequestA $request) //RequestA extends AbstractRequest 
    {
       ...
    }
}

сlass ResultHandlerB extends AbstractResultHandler
{
    public function handle(string $name, RequestB $request) //RequestB extends AbstractRequest 
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Такой код вызывает ошибку. Работать будет, если в функциях указать к примеру интерфейс, но тогда теряется информация о том, какой конкретно тип требуется в соотв. функции: рефлексия не поможет, подсказок в IDE не будет и пр., если не использовать PHPDoc.

Короче, вопрос в том, почему php не даёт возможность использовать такую форму записи, вроде с т.з. логики никаких нарушений и двойственных толкований нет.

Comment: Понятно что вопрос конкретный, но в целом, тут налицо применение паттерна. Какая-нибудь фабрика явно подошла бы И для всего это действа достаточно было вызвать метод у общего класса, который динамически создаст и нужный Request и прокинет ruj в нужный ResultHandler

Comment: с точки зрения логики, любой ваш созданный экземпляр `HandlerX` должен уметь принимать экземпляр базового `Request`. То есть берете массив неизвестных наследников handler-ов, и работаете с неизвестным request. По итогу подобными декларациями подобный код будет падать, хотя абстракция говорит, что должен работать. Тут речь примерно о том же, что в родителе сделать функцию публичной, а в наследнике приватной (то есть уменьшить видимость). Вы же не всегда работаете с конкретными наследниками, часто никто не знает конкретный используемый тип, и работает основываясь на знаниях о родителе.